# UIStoryboard instantiate new UIViewController object every time a segue is performed?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I just realised that using Storyboards with a UITableViewController with 2 static cells executing a modal segue to display 2 different UIViewControllers is actually creating every time a NEW instance of those view controllers, each time calling initWithCoder: method (and then of course viewDidLoad). I always thought the same instances were used and initWithCoder: was called only once per view controller class.

Can someone confirm this behaviour is correct? I am not using anything fancy, not even prepareForSegue:

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Yep this is normal. 'Modal' views tend to be temporary and when dismissed are thrown away. There shouldn't be any need to avoid it really?

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is 'by design' in the current version of iOS (I confirmed this with 2 Apple engineers at WWDC '13), but it could be changed in a future update. There's no way to avoid it that I know of when using storyboards. If you went back to a xib for every controller you could manage caching instances yourself.